# iOS 7: showing a popover from a search bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UISearchBar` in an iPad app. When the search bar begins editing, I show a popover below the search bar containing search suggestions and previous searches:

[image]

This is a long-standing interaction in the app. Now under iOS 7, everything behind the popover (in terms of z-axis) looks dimmed — presumably, the `UIView` the popover adds over the top of the window is no longer transparent. This means the search bar that the user is currently editing in looks like it's no longer active. It *is* still active (the user can still select text in the search bar and tap the Delete button to clear the search bar's text), but it bugs me a bit that it looks like it's inactive.

What are my options for dealing with this change in how popovers work in iOS 7?

Here's what I've come up with so far:

- try and restore the behaviour of iOS 6 by making the popover's window's background clear (there's nothing to allow this in `UIPopoverController`, so I imagine it would involve digging around and finding the popover's window)
- stop using `UIPopoverController` and try mimicking it with my own view controller that dims everything but the search bar

Am I missing something obvious? Both options (and the other dumb/crazy options I thought about) seem nontrivial to implement and/or bad ideas for a few different reasons.

Apple's sample project for demonstrating this kind of functionality, [ToolbarSearch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009461-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), exhibits the same behaviour as my app. This dimmed-out search bar can't be the best experience for users. By way of example, consider Calendar for iPad: it went from having a search bar in the navigation bar that shows a popover beneath it when it's active (just like my app) to just showing a search icon that shows a popover *containing* a search bar. I imagine the change was made because of the problem I've run into here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest and most user friendly thing to do would be to move the search bar into the `UIPopover`. To remove the dim you are going to have to write your own `UIPopoverBackgroundView`. If you want to see how to do it, take a look [here](https://github.com/ddebin/DDPopoverBackgroundView).

Comment: I didn't think that was what `UIPopoverBackgroundView` replacements like `DDPopoverBackgroundView` were for — aren't they for customising the popover background (i.e. customising the arrow, the little bit of chrome around the content view controller), not the window the popover appears over the top of? At any rate, yeah, it's looking like the best thing to do will be to follow Apple's lead and move the search bar into the popover.

Comment: It seems to affect all of it. I popped DDPopoverBackgroundView into Apple's ToolbarSearch sample code and noticed the dim was gone. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/H2h1pPF